# Selecting/matching elements in a namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml and xsl that need to generate another xml, but because of 'xmlns', it generates an empty xml. Without 'xmlns' in the root of XML, it works fine.  The following XSL is not a complete version yet. I need to put more logic into it, but I am stuck in here, because of 'xmlns'.

I am using Java API to generate another XML with this XML and XSL. Can somebody tell me why it can't match the element because of the xmlns and how to fix it?

Thanks.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config xmlns="http://xmlns.company.com/config">
   <subi-config>
     <primary-data-source>Repository</primary-data-source>
     <instance>
       <name>agent1</name>
       <address>localhost</address>
       <port>8080</port>
       <admin-username>admin</admin-username>
     </instance>
   </subi-config>
 </config>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://xmlns.company.com/config">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="config"/>
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template  match="config">
        <config>
          <sub-config>
        <primary-data-source><xsl:value-of select="sub-config/primary-data-source"/></primary-data-source>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sub-config"/>
      </sub-config>
    </config>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="sub-config">
        <xsl:for-each select="instance">

            <instance>
              <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
              <address><xsl:value-of select="address"/></address>
                <port><xsl:value-of select="port"/></port>
              <admin-username><xsl:value-of select="admin-username"/></admin-username>
            </instance>

        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have modified your title, since just about every XSLT question is about "transforming xml into another xml".

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a prefix to the namespace and use that prefix when addressing the elements of the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cfg="http://xmlns.company.com/config"
exclude-result-prefixes="cfg"> 

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates  select="cfg:config"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="cfg:config">
    <config>
        <sub-config>
            <primary-data-source>
                <xsl:value-of select="cfg:sub-config/cfg:primary-data-source"/>
            </primary-data-source>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cfg:sub-config"/>
        </sub-config>
    </config>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cfg:sub-config">
    <xsl:for-each select="cfg:instance">
        <instance>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="cfg:name"/></name>
            <address><xsl:value-of select="cfg:address"/></address>
            <port><xsl:value-of select="cfg:port"/></port>
            <admin-username><xsl:value-of select="cfg:admin-username"/></admin-username>
        </instance>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that `sub-config` and `subi-config` are two different things.

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there any way to do it without prefix?

Comment: In theory, yes - but it would be both complicated and inefficient. Why do you object to doing it the right way?

Comment: I am not objecting to it. I just want to know if there is any alternative.

Comment: @user826323 - one way to do with without the namespace-prefix is to match on element `*` and use predicate filters to match the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`: *[local-name()='sub-config' and namespace-uri()='http://xmlns.company.com/config']. You could also just match the `local-name()` if you aren't concerned with mixed namespaces and ambiguous matches: `*[local-name()='sub-config']`. However, it is a lot more concise and a best practice to use namespace-prefixes.

Comment: Also, in XSLT 2.0 you can register an xpath-default-namespace with the `xsl:stylesheet/@xpath-default-namespace` and you can use wildcards for the namespace `*:sub-config`.

Answer (score -1):

Use xsl:element with namespace attribute

```
<xsl:template  match="config">
  <xsl:element namespace="http://xmlns.company.com/config" name="config">
     <sub-config>
       <primary-data-source><xsl:value-of select="sub-config/primary-data-source"/></primary-data-source>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="sub-config"/>
    </sub-config>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

It will create element with computed name( Static for us ) and allow to add namespace attribute