# How get <dc:title> value in XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to get a value in my XML file using XSL.
I'm trying to get the value of this :

```
<publication id="1708" name="Jimmy" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title>MY TITLE</dc:title>
</publication>
```

I've try many solutions, but it doesn't works.
This is my xsl code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <title>
    <xsl:template match="dc:title">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    </title>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thx to answer me
Jimmy

Comment: This is a namespace issue. See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086520/selecting-matching-elements-in-a-namespace/24086688#24086688 -- Note also that templates cannot be nested.

Comment: @VMAtm "*Remove dc: from your `match.*" That's not a good advice.

Comment: It's not a namespace issue. There are nested templates.

Comment: When I remove the `dc:` in my match i have this error : `Error loading stylesheet: Failed to parse an XSLT stylesheet.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you have nested two templates. Templates are not nested. Instead you apply them. The stylesheet below should solve your problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

    <xsl:template match="publication">
        <html>
           <head>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:title"/>
           </head>
           <body>
           </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dc:title">    
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </title>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've made a couple of other modifications - if you want code that's easy to maintain, use `xsl:apply-templates` where you were using `xsl:value-of`. I've also fixed your html header section. I've also modified your template to match the root element rather than the document node (`publication` instead of `/`)

In order to use this stylesheet you will need to save it to a file (let's say `style.xsl` and we will save it to the same directory as the xml file).  Then you will need to modify your XML file to look like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<publication id="1708" name="Jimmy" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title>MY TITLE</dc:title>
</publication>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i've also thir error `Error loading stylesheet: Failed to parse an XSLT stylesheet.`. When i type this in my xml `type="text/xslt"` this display my xml file full.

Comment: What sort of environment are you using here?

Comment: Using Firefox 29.0.1 and Windows 7.

Comment: So you have something like `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystyle.xsl"?>` at the top of your XML file? The "text/xslt" might be your problem - it should be `test/xsl` but that really sounds like a syntax error in the stylesheet itself. The example I gave you above is a a valid stylesheet so shouldn't give that error.

Comment: Yes, i have this `<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" type="text/xsl" href="F53.xsl" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"?>` at the 2nd line of my xml file. But i have the error. I don't understand Why, just want the `dc:title` value ... :(

Comment: I have modified my solution to give you an example of you should be using this. If you still have an error then you have an error in  your XSLT file.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have this error, but now, it display ALL of my xml file ... I'm trying to search ...

Comment: I'ts finaly WORKS with this code :
`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

    <xsl:template match="Publication">
        <html>
           <head>
    <title>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:title" >
      <xsl:for-each select="Publication">
       <xsl:value-of select="dc:title" />
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </title>
    
    <body>

    </body>
           </head>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`