# I'm having issues transforming an XML to another XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm kind of a beginner in xml and at the moment i'm working on transforming an XML to another XML using XSLT. However i can't figure out why it's not working at the moment. I would love it if you could explain the issue here.

Here's my XMLFile1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTFile1.xslt"?>

<School
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com XMLSchema1.xsd">


  <NameOfSchool>FCB</NameOfSchool>

  <Child>

    <FirstName>Sally</FirstName>
    <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
    <P-Number>1008021245</P-Number>


    <Sibling>
      <P-Number>0005052464</P-Number>
      <FirstName>Art</FirstName>
      <LastName>Vandelay</LastName>

    </Sibling>

    <Other>

      <Allergies>No</Allergies>
      <AMS>No</AMS>


    </Other>

  </Child>



  <Parent1>

    <FirstName>H.E</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pennypecker</LastName>
    <P-Number>7806032356</P-Number>
    <Adress>4 Yawkey Way Boston, Massachusetts 02215</Adress>


    <Contact>

      <Phone>
        <Work>0522375796</Work>
        <Home>0522597068</Home>
      </Phone>

    </Contact>


  </Parent1>


  <Parent2>

    <FirstName>Kel</FirstName>
    <LastName>Varnsen</LastName>
    <P-Number>7806089645</P-Number>
    <Adress>1 East 161st Street Bronx, New York City, New York 10451</Adress>

    <Contact>

      <Phone>
        <Work>0522596847</Work>
        <Home>0522597068</Home>
      </Phone>

    </Contact>

  </Parent2>


</School>
```

And here is my XSLTFile1.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Parent1">
      <BGI>
        <Parent1>
          <P-Number>
            <xsl:value-of select="P-Number"/>
          </P-Number>
          <FirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
          </FirstName>
          <LastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
          </LastName>
        </Parent1>

      </BGI>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent2">
    <BGI>
      <Parent2>
        <P-Number>
          <xsl:value-of select="P-Number"/>
        </P-Number>
        <FirstName>
          <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
        </FirstName>
        <LastName>
          <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
        </LastName>
      </Parent2>

    </BGI>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i want is the new XML Document to look like this:

```
<BGI>
  <Parent1>
    <P-Number>7806032356</P-Number>
    <FirstName>H.E</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pennypecker</LastName>
  <Parent1>

   <Parent2>
    <P-Number>7806089645</P-Number>
    <FirstName>Kel</FirstName>
    <LastName>Varnsen</LastName>
  <Parent2>
</BGI>
```

Comment: What *is not working at the moment*? And what is your desired result?

Comment: The XML document is uneaffected by the XSLT. Correct me if i'm wrong but shouldn't the XML document only show the elements specified on the XSL? Right now it shows the whole file with all elements.

Comment: your example XML uses the XML namespace `http://www.w3schools.com` (by setting `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"`), whereas your XSLT assumes the elements to transform are in no namespace. try using `xmlns:xxx="http://www.w3schools.com"` in your XSLT's `<xsl:stylesheet>` document element, and then match `xxx:Parent` and so forth.

Comment: @dret Hello. Sorry for my ignorance but can you kind of show an example of what you mean using my code? I tried using the w3schools namespace in XSLT stylesheet but nothing is changed.

Comment: @Rengaw **1.** Please post the result you expect to get. You speak of transforming XML to HTML - but your stylesheet does not even attempt to do that: HTML has no <BGI> element .  - **2.** "*Right now it shows the whole file with all elements.*" No, it does not. It only shows the whole **text** of the document. That is a result of the built-in template rules being applied. Your templates do not match anything, because your XML declares a namespace. This is a frequent question - for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086520/selecting-matching-elements-in-a-namespace/24086688#24086688

Comment: @michael.hor257k Well i want the result to only show the elements of Parent1 and Parent2 from the original XML if that makes sense. That's why i tried to match those two templates in the XSLT file.

Comment: @Rengaw I am afraid that's too vague. HTML has many ways of showing data: table, list, paragraphs, etc. Please post the exact HTML code you want to be used to "*show the elements of Parent1 and Parent2*".

Comment: @michael.hor257k I want to transform my current XML to an XML only containing the information from the Parent1 and Parent2 elements. So i want the document only to display the values in these elements.

Comment: @Rengaw Then why are you asking about (X)HTML?

Comment: I mean the values specifically from P-Number, FirstName and LastName in Parent1 and Parent2.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Maybe the question was formulated wrongly but do you get what i'm trying to do? Perhaps i ought to edit the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected result can be achieved using the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3schools.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:School">
    <BGI>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:Parent1 | ns1:Parent2"/>
    </BGI>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:Parent1 | ns1:Parent2">
    <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:P-Number | ns1:FirstName | ns1:LastName"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. The use of a prefix to address elements in the source XML;
2. The use of `xsl:element` instead of `xsl:copy` to re-create the
   "copied" elements in no-namespace.

Comment: Nevermind, i deleted my old response to this post and tried it again and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: @Rengaw It seems we are back to the original confusion. Browsers are not designed to display XML - esp. not XML after XSL transformation to another XML. I am not sure what your ultimate purpose here is. Perhaps you need to use another tool to do your transformation.

Comment: Right. Yeah no,  i'm probably just confused. You did solve my problem though so again, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You only write to the `<Parent1>` and `<Parent2>` templates. You do not write to the `<NameOfSchool>` or `<Child>` templates (the other siblings). As a result, they are rendered exactly the same in the output. If you want to remove the latter nodes, write an empty template as below shows.

Specifically, the Identity Transform copies all content as is and the empty templates remove those referenced nodes. I use pipe delimiter (`|`) to apply union of the referenced sets. The namespace `doc` is declared in XSLT, purely an arbitrary chosen name since you have an undeclared namespace in XML document in `<School>` opening tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                              xmlns:doc="http://www.w3schools.com"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com XMLSchema1.xsd"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl doc">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Empty template to remove nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:NameOfSchool|doc:Child"/>

  <!-- Rewrite of needed nodes, doc/value-of/local-name all used to handle namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:Parent1|doc:Parent2">
    <BGI>
      <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'>
        <P-Number><xsl:value-of select="doc:P-Number"/></P-Number>
        <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="doc:FirstName"/></FirstName>
        <LastName><xsl:value-of select="doc:LastName"/></LastName>
      </xsl:element>
    </BGI>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By the way, when viewing this xml in a browser the stylesheet will be applied but original XML content will show in page source. And because the final outputted XML does not contain any HTML markup (`<div>, <table>, <p>, <span>`) only values will appear.

Comment: This does not transform XML to HTML.